# Modifiy response from GraphQL & Orchard

Tags: graphql, orchardcms, graphiql

I am using Graphql queries to access our Orchard CMS api to receive content for my web page

In my case I have three different part I need to access from a page lets call them table1, table2 and table3

If I wanted to fetch the content form these three tables it would look something like this: see picture
[image]

My question now is: Is it possible to group the objects in the queries response together like:

```
"data":{
  contentArray:[
    table:{
       tableOne: {}
       tableTwo:{}
       tableThree:{}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Essentially no and it's not a limitation of orchard but of graphql(that I know of). What is your use case? What would you expect if there are multiple elements in contentArray `table:..., table:...,table:...,`?

Here are [basics of graphql queries][1], maybe aliases will be enough for you to rename contentArray to table


  [1]: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/